# Finding the maximum value of $\frac{\tan(\theta+\frac{2\pi}3)-\tan(\theta+\frac\pi6)+\cos(\theta+\frac\pi6)}{\sqrt3}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, trigonometry

**Question:**

If $\theta\in[-\frac{5\pi}{12},-\frac\pi3]$ and maximum value of $\frac{\tan(\theta+\frac{2\pi}3)-\tan(\theta+\frac\pi6)+\cos(\theta+\frac\pi6)}{\sqrt3}$ is $\frac ab$ (where $a$ and $b$ are co-primes), find $a-b$

**Attempt $1$:**

$\frac{\tan\theta-\sqrt3}{1+\sqrt3\tan\theta}-\frac{\tan\theta+\frac1{\sqrt3}}{1-\frac{\tan\theta}{\sqrt3}}+\frac{\sqrt3\cos\theta}2-\frac{\sin\theta}2$

Taking LCM and getting,

$\frac{-4\sec^2\theta}{(1+\sqrt3\tan\theta)(\sqrt3-\tan\theta)}+\frac{\sqrt3\cos\theta}2-\frac{\sin\theta}2$

Not able to move further.

**Attempt $2$:**

Converting $\tan$ into $\sin$, $\cos$, taking LCM, and getting

$\frac1{\cos(\theta+\frac{2\pi}3)\cos(\theta+\frac{\pi}6)}+\cos(\theta+\frac{\pi}6)$

Not able to proceed next.

**Attempt $3$:**

$f'(\theta)=\sec^2(\theta+\frac{2\pi}3)-\sec^2(\theta+\frac{\pi}6)-\sin(\theta+\frac{\pi}6)$

Not able to proceed from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on @Claude Leibovici's answer, rewrite as
$$A=\cos(x)-2\csc(2x)$$

Now, $$A'=-\sin(x)+4\csc(2x)\cot(2x)=\frac{4\cos(2x)-\sin^2(2x)\sin(x)}{\sin^2(2x)}$$

$$\implies A'=\frac 4{\sin^2(2x)}\cdot \left( {\cos(2x)-\sin^3(x)\cos^2(x)} \right)$$

As $x\in \Big[-\frac{\pi}{4},-\frac\pi6\Big]$, $-\sin^3(x)>0$ and $\cos(2x)\ge0$. Squares are always non-negative, which tells us that $$A'>0 \space\forall \space x \in\Big[-\frac{\pi}{4},-\frac\pi6\Big]$$

Thus, the maximum value occurs at $x=-\frac \pi6$
$$\implies A_{\text {max}}=\frac{11\sqrt3}6$$

This, in your original expression gives the maximum value as $\frac ab=\frac{11}6$
$$\implies a-b=5$$

(Thanks @Claude Leibovici for reminding me to add the ending lines)

Comment: Good job for sure (don't forget to divide the end rusult by $\sqrt 3$ to get the coprimes). (+1)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Oops! Forgot what we were solving for...I will edit it in. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

At least, you could start simplifying the expression writing
$$A=\tan(\theta+\frac{2\pi}3)-\tan(\theta+\frac\pi6)+\cos(\theta+\frac\pi6)$$ as
$$A=\cos \left(\theta +\frac{\pi }{6}\right)-\tan \left(\theta +\frac{\pi
   }{6}\right)-\cot \left(\theta +\frac{\pi }{6}\right)$$ Now, let $x=\theta +\frac{\pi }{6}$ to make
$$A=\cos(x)-\tan(x)-\cot(x)\qquad \text{with} \qquad   x\in\Big[-\frac{\pi}{4},-\frac\pi6\Big]$$ Simplifying again
$$A=\cos (x)-\csc (x) \sec (x)$$

Comment: Hi. I already have this version in Attempt $2$. But yes, I had not converted it into a complementary angle. So, thank you for that. After this, shall we go for derivative?

Comment: Actually for functions involving trigonometric functions, I prefer trying to write them as one single trig function by all those formulas, instead of taking derivative, but you can try taking the derivative to see if you get any solvable equations I guess...

Comment: @VitalsBat, we have $$A=\cos x-\frac2{\sin2x}$$ Can we write this as one trig function?

Comment: @aarbee. I am sorry ! I did not see it. Write the derivative (simple). Use the tangent half-angle substitution to get a polynomial and show that it does not have any real root.

Comment: @aarbee oops I forgot to check that there's a range for $x$, to make it into one trig function should be for all $x \in [-\infty,\infty]$

I think for this question you can differentiate, giving you $-sin(x)-\frac{4sin(2x)}{cos^2(2x)}$ I suppose, for my method, since sin(x) is negative in the interval $[-\frac{\pi}{4},-\frac{\pi}{6}], [-\frac{\pi}{2},-\frac{\pi}{3}]$ and $cos^2(2x) \geqslant 0$ for $[-\frac{\pi}{4},-\frac{\pi}{6}]$ so since $derivative > 0$, the largest value of the expression is when $x=\frac{\pi}{6}$.